# Systemic bugs in GraphPlot and related functions such as TreePlot and TreeForm

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, visualization

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I believe I have come across a rather curious bug in [`TreeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TreeForm.html):

```
{"foo", "bar", "Plot"} // TreeForm
```

[image]

Note that the string `"Plot"` is formatted as `True`.

Unless I have accidentally changed something in my configuration this must be a bug.

I am using version 10.0.0 under Windows.

---

*It turns out that the problem is far larger and more widespread than the initial manifestation indicated.  Please see my self-answer for an analysis of this systemic problem.*

Comment: This is the same result in V9.0.1 Windows 8.1

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks for the report.  I'm surprised this hasn't been noticed before.  (Assuming this post is not a duplicate.)

Comment: This almost feels like an easter egg. :) Because in my impression, the internal process of strings in `TreeForm` should be a one-liner. No room to make mistake.

Comment: @trVoldemort Should be a one-liner?  Get ready for a surprise.  Try:  `TracePrint[ToBoxes @ TreeForm @ "Plot", TraceInternal -> True]`  (Be ready to kill the kernel.)

Comment: Confirmed on Linux, for v9 and v10.

Comment: By doing `TreeForm` on all symbols, and search for `True`, only `Plot` (and `True` itself) gives `True` :)

Comment: @YiWang Thanks for doing the search.  It mirrors my own result.  (I only scanned ``System` `` Symbols.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

---

Although this is hardly a debilitating bug I wondered what *else* might be affected so I decided to trace this further.  I found that the bug affects `TreeForm` by way of [`TreePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreePlot.html).  Here is a reduced example of the call that originates in the exhibit above:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4}, Top, 1, 
 "VertexNames" -> {List, HoldForm["foo"], HoldForm["bar"], HoldForm["Plot"]}, 
 VertexLabeling -> All
]
```

[image]

This ends up calling `` Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`TreePlot2 `` which uses `` Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`GraphPlotInternalRuleList23D `` which ultimately becomes:

```
Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`GraphPlot23DInternalLabels[TreePlot, 
 SparseArray[Automatic, {4, 4}, 0, {1, {{0, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {{2}, {3}, {4}}}, {1, 1, 1}}],
 2, "Plot", "RuleList", {1, 2, 3, 4},
 Method -> {"LayeredDrawing", "Root" -> 1, "LayerSizeFunction" -> (1 &), "Rotation" -> 0},
 "VertexNames" -> {List, "foo", "bar", "Plot"}, VertexLabeling -> All,
 "EdgeLabels" -> None, "VertexTooltips" -> None, "EdgeTooltips" -> None]
```

And spelunking the trace of this command eventually leads us to:

```
{List, "foo", "bar", "Plot"} /. {"VertexTooltips" -> Automatic, 
  "EdgeTooltips" -> Automatic, "EdgeLabels" -> Automatic, "VertexNames" -> Automatic, 
  "VertexSizes" -> Automatic, "VertexColor" -> Automatic, "EdgeColor" -> Automatic, 
  "VertexFrameBackground" -> Automatic, "VertexFrameStyle" -> Automatic, 
  "VertexFrameMargins" -> Automatic, "VertexTextStyle" -> True, "Plot" -> True}
```

So it seems I have finally found the origin of the problem.  Let's test it:

```
{"VertexTooltips", "EdgeTooltips", "EdgeLabels", "VertexNames", "VertexSizes", 
  "VertexColor", "EdgeColor", "VertexFrameBackground", "VertexFrameStyle", 
  "VertexFrameMargins", "VertexTextStyle", "Plot"} // TreeForm
```

[image]

**Those ALL are incorrectly replaced.**

Viewing the definition with:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions @ Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`GraphPlot23DInternalLabels
```

we find a whole series of operations like:

```
vnames =             (* contexts omitted for clarity *)
 "VertexNames" /. 
   processOptionNames[Flatten[{opts}]] /. 
     processOptionNames[hiddenOptions[caller]]
```

(`processOptionNames` is `` Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`processOptionNames `` and it converts Option names into strings.)

**Can you see the problem?**  The first `ReplaceAll` finds the value of `"VertexNames"` in explicit options, if it exists, but *then* the second `ReplaceAll` operates on *that value* rather than `"VertexNames"`! *This is careless programming and it should never have lasted all this time in production code.*

Since the problem is not limited to vertex names we can demonstrate other peculiar bugs such as this:

```
ticks = {{0.8, "Prelude"}, {0.7, "Epilog"},
         {0.5, "Axes"}, {0.4, "Ticks"},
         {0.2, "Foreground"}, {0.1, "Background"}};

TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{True, ticks}, {False, False}}]
```

[image]

[`GraphPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html) is also affected:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4},
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{True, ticks}, {False, False}}]
```

[image]

A double application of `ReplaceAll` should never be used to extract option values.  Yet disturbingly it seems that is has been used repeatedly.

Fortunately [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) appears unaffected, but one must wonder what other internal functions might also be affected?

Comment: May also need examination: ``System`GeoPlotsDump`iGeoRegionValuePlot``, ``Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`MatrixPlotInternal``

Comment: Quick fix: `treeForm[args__] := 
  TreeForm @@ ({args} /. 
     s_String :> StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[62304], s]);                            
graphPlot[args__] := 
  GraphPlot @@ ({args} /. 
     s_String :> StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[62304], s]);`

Comment: Excellent diagnosis, as always! This double use of `ReplaceAll` is indeed quite disturbing, and we are investigating.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your attention, as always. :-)

Comment: Looks like this code was written before modern option processing functions like `OptionValue` were implemented (V6). We have fixed some of the most serious cases identified here.

Comment: @Stefan I'm sure that even before v6 other methods were standard.  I found a number of cases that still do not use `OptionValue` but simply join the lists, i.e. `"OptionName" /. Join[ Flatten[{opts}],      hiddenOptions[caller] ]`.  I think so long as each element in `Join` is assured of being a `List` and not `$Failed` or whatever this should be robust, right?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was vague. It is certainly possible to have robust option processing code without the V6+ features (e.g. I think your example should work fine). The buggy `GraphPlot` code was always bad. I just meant that it's now much much easier to do these things :-)