# Unexpected behavior using `ReplaceAll[]` for nested lists

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

`ReplaceAll[]` might lead to unexpected behavior (at least it surprised me).
I use `ReplaceAll[]` to convert a list (basically data cleanup).

For the command:

```
{{1, "2"}, {2, "3"}} /. {x_, _ } :> {x, "SOMETHING"}
```

I expected

```
{{1, "SOMETHING"}, {2, "SOMETHING"}}
```

but got

```
{{1, "2"}, "SOMETHING"}.
```

Comment: It is extremely important to remember that the pattern _ in Mathematica matches every expression. In particular {x_, _ } matches the expression {list1,list2} and gives {list1, "Something"}

Comment: Stricter pattern matching would have saved you: `{{1, "2"}, {2, "3"}} /.
 {x_Integer, _String} :> {x, "SOMETHING"}`

Comment: @J.M. It could have saved him, but it is not good practice.  `/.` is much too tempting because it is short.  People should always default to `Replace` (or in some cases `Lookup`) and use `ReplaceAll` only for algebraic replacements (or when replacing at all levels is required).

Comment: Related: [(7519)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7519/121),
[(46991)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46991/121), [(56010)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56010/121),
[(124962)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124962/121)

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't (entirely) agree with that.  I think `/.` can often be used well given a little thought, and I find *defaulting* to `Replace` a bit heavy handed.  Of course [there are cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121) where `Replace` is far superior, but in many other cases I would argue that a pattern restriction as J. M. offered is entirely adequate and not bad practice. [Careless use of `/.`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55726/121) is just that: carelessness, and IMHO baroque code is not a remedy for that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would not call using `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll` baroque.  The shorthand `/.` is a minor convenience only.  I do sloppily use `/.` when working interactively, but when writing code which is expected to be robust, it is a good idea to use [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).  Even the smartest programmer makes mistakes, or fails to see consequences sometimes. It is good practice to try to make our programs predictable and to reduce the chance of mistakes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think that if the goal is to replace at level 1, then that's exactly what one should do, and not try to come up with a pattern that won't match at deeper level under any circumstances. What if this function is in a continually maintained package, and one year later you relax the requirements on the function's input *but forget to update that special pattern that only prevents deeper-level matching if the input is of a certain kind*?

Comment: @Szabolcs We should discuss this another time in more detail.  I probably don't disagree with you in practice.  Too sleepy now, and comments aren't the place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`ReplaceAll` is way overused**, and it can very easily lead to unexpected results (or bugs in your code) because it replaces *at all levels*.  In fact, the example you show is one of the most common errors stemming from the misuse of `ReplaceAll`.

I recommend using `ReplaceAll` *only when you know you need it*, except for algebraic replacements.

Otherwise, **use `Replace`**:

```
Replace[{{1, "2"}, {2, "3"}}, {x_, _ } :> {x, "SOMETHING"}, {1}]
```

Make `Replace` your default choice unless you know why you need `ReplaceAll`, especially when developing packages (where robustness is a requirement).

Of course, when doing interactive work, a bit of sloppiness if forgivable :-)  `/.` is just shorter to type.

Comment: +1. You make a very good point. It is rather surprising that this has not been emphasized enough on this site for such a long time, or may be I just don't remember.

Comment: "I recommend using ReplaceAll only when you know you need it, except for algebraic replacements" seems a bit extreme.  I think better advice is "use as specific pattern as possible when using `ReplaceAll`", for example `{_Integer,_}` in this case.  I guess my POV is the subtly different "`Replace` is way underused".  It's a great function and often exactly what you need, but it isn't a substitute for `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: FWIW, I did some work in the last year (I think for 11.1, but I'd have to double check) expanding the ref pages for `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, and `ReplaceRepeated` to both clarify what each did and the relationships between them, and I do address this point.  But I think I'll add a simpler example focusing exactly on `ReplaceAll` based on this question.

Comment: @Itai If you are working on the documentation pages, one difference you may want to point out is that `ReplaceAll` works "from the outside towards the inside" and `Replace` works "from the inside towards the outside".  Thus it is not possible to do use `Replace` to do precisely what `ReplaceAll` does.  I'm not sure how to phrase this concisely and clearly :-)

Comment: I suggest you look at the 4th, 5th, and 7th Properties & Relations examples for `Replace`.  I think they are documenting exactly what your trying to say.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev I looked only under Details originally, but I can see how it is difficult to squeeze this in there.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the provided pattern *also* matches the **outer list**.
Therefore `ReplaceAll[]` replaces the outer list and stops (as there are no elements left).

To overcome this issue, `Map[]` must be used:

```
ReplaceAll[{x_, _} :> {x, "SOMETHING"}] /@ {{1, "2"}, {2, "3"}}
```

Comment: +1. Actually, David Wagner discusses exactly this case in his book, I think in the chapter on patterns and pattern-matching. It is a very common source of errors in Mathematica.