# ReplaceAll with StringContains

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I would like to replace lists within a list based on a string pattern with a blank sequence:

```
list = {{"", "abc"}, {"", "ooobc"}};  
rules = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, ___~~ "bc"}->"y"};  
ReplaceAll[list, rules]
{"x", {"", _ ~~ "ooobc"}}
```

I would like to replace `{"", "ooobc"}` with `"y"`. Since I tried from different angles - is there an elegant approach to use `ReplaceAll` with some kind of `StringContainsQ` logic?

Edit:
One of the comments solves my problem well, so for completeness I add here:
`rules = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, _?(StringMatchQ[___ ~~ "bc"])} -> "y"}`;

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Does something like `rules = {{_String, _?(StringMatchQ["abc", #] &)} -> "x"};` work for you?

Comment: I would like to replace based on a StringContains logic, i.e. if a String within any of the sublists contains "bc" as 2nd element, it should be replaced.

Comment: `rules = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, x_} /; StringContainsQ[x, "bc"] -> 
    "y"};` like that?

Comment: Or, if you need something more general than `StringContainsQ`: `rules = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, _?(StringMatchQ[___ ~~ "bc"])} -> "y"};`

Comment: [This applies here as well.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156541/12)

Comment: @Mathe172: This works very well as solution to my problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
condition = StringEndsQ["bc"];
rules = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, _?condition} -> "y"};
(* or rules = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, _?(StringEndsQ["bc"])} -> "y"}; *)

ReplaceAll[list, rules]
```

> {"x", "y"}

You can also use `StringMatchQ["*bc"]` or `StringContainsQ["bc"]` in place of `StringEndsQ["bc"]`.

Alternatively, you can use [`Condition (/;)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) instead of [`PatternTest (?)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) :

```
rules2 = {{_, "abc"} -> "x", {_, x_ /; condition[x]} -> "y"};

ReplaceAll[list, rules2]
```

> {"x", "y"}